# iphone API for rails login cannot receive parameters in JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

API url :  : `http://www.example.com/users/sign_in`

Params  : `{"user":{"login":"test","password":"test123$"},"commit":"Login"}`

after submit :

```
  Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-10 17:10:20 +0530
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
{"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"sessions"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

and the function is

```
def create
 respond_to do |format|    
   ........
   params[:user][:login]   # this value give nil for JSON format
  .... .....  
 end 
end
```

But for the same works in HTML format

Comment: What does `p params` print?

Comment: Use `format.json` under respond_to loop

Comment: my issue is cannot get params value

Comment: how are you passing the params because they are clearly not being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content_type header to `application/json`. This is needed for all `POST` or `PATCH` calls.

Also add `.json` to the end of the url so that Rails will auto translate the JSON to params.